# Как сделать заглавные буквы в URL d Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url

В URL надо сделать кириллицу с заглавными буквами, пытался вручную в БД поменять но не нашел.

Comment: Кириллицы вообще не бывает в урлах. Это браузеры (но не все) показывают

Comment: С кириллицей у меня проблем нет, он сразу ее поставил. А вот с заглавными...

Comment: Речь не пор тебя, а про интернет. Частью которого является и твой сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Для `.htaccess` примерно так:

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteMap lc int:tolower RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z] RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Но поскольку здесь используется Wordpress со своей системой постоянных ссылок, возможны нюансы.

Кроме этого, следует учесть следующие негативные факторы данного подхода:

а. На разных серверах - разные правила капитализации URL.

б. Возникает опасность дублирования контента и поисковой пессимизации.

Поэтому лучше не использовать худшие практики, лучше использовать лучшие практики :)